# Call Javascript function inside block

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, magento-1.7

I want to call to JavaScript function which is in the template file of the block. The block has the following button. For that button's onclick event I want to call that JavaScript function. How to do it?

Block button is as follows.

```
protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $onclick = "submitAndReloadArea($('order_history_block').parentNode, '".$this->getSubmitUrl()."')";
        $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button')
            ->setData(array(
                'label'   => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Submit Comment'),
                'class'   => 'save',
                'onclick' => $onclick
            ));
        $this->setChild('submit_button', $button);
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: please any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("submit_button").onclick = function () { 
    yourJavascriptFunc();//Calling your javascript function when slicks the submit button
};
```

Comment: I have a javascript function in template file. I want to call that function for the onclick event

Comment: It's not working. I need something like  $onclick = "testfuction()";